# look (at) what you've done

Tags: prepositions

Look what you've done this time.

Look **at** what you've done this time.

Now, is using the preposition wrong here?
How does one know when to follow look with at, and when not to?

What about these constructions :

Look (at) how much damage you've done.
Just look (at) how good my car looks.

Comment: In common speech (but not in formal writing) "at" can be omitted when some question words follow _look,_ especially in the imperative mood (as in your examples.) "Look how much you ate!" "Look where you're going." "Look who you danced with."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Look (at)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/look_1?q=look)*** in your example is used with to attract attention to a possible problem or danger. The preposition "at" is generally omitted before when, what, why etc:

> - ***pay attention***:
>
>   - *[intransitive, transitive] to pay attention to something
>       look (at something)*
>   - ***Look at the time! We're going to be late.***
>   - ***Look where, what, etc…*** Can't you look where you're going?*

OLD